# Cross-domain jQuery AJAX file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, nginx, cross-domain

So the point is I have a subdomain which is API endpoint for uploading files. But when I'm trying to upload anything with jQuery to this subdomain (from main www domain) I'm getting error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://1.storage.site.net/upload. Origin http://www.site.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I tried everything: headers in nginx, headers in source code, I even tried sending file to stub file with just

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');

echo json_encode(['lulz' => 123]);
```

In two words: NOTHING WORKS.

BUT. I noticed that small files (~1MB) upload correctly and files a little bit larger (say 5MB) — NOT (origin not allowed).

Is there any way of solving that?

Comment: It's odd that the small files work. I'd expect nothing to work at all, since it's a violation of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: @Mike that's why he's sending the `Access-Control-*` headers. They tell the browser, "I know it's a violation of the policy, but it's cool, man." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is that the 5MB file is too large for Apache's `max_request_body` setting (or whatever its name was), leading to the PHP script not being executed, thus never getting to send those headers, which in turns generates the misleading cross domain error.

If this assumption is true, you should be seeing more details  in your browser's "Net" tab - the upload script should be returning an error condition of some sort.

To debug, you could do a normal form-based file upload, test that, and adjust things until it works.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that browsers can't show 413 error properly. When I tried to upload file not with AJAX but directly (with html form) I received 412 html error. It was about nginx client_max_body_size setting.

Comment: Well, if this was the answer, check it off.